# Calculate row sum value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I am new to R and would like to get some advice on how to perform sum calculation in data frame structure.

```
       year value
Row 1  2001  10
Row 2  2001  20
Row 3  2002  15
Row 4  2002  NA
Row 5  2003  5
```

How can I use R to return the total sum value by year? Many thanks!

```
       year  sum value
Row 1  2001  30
Row 2  2002  15
Row 3  2003  5
```

Comment: take a look at. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do that.
One of them is using the function aggregate like this:

```
year <- c(2001,2001,2002,2002,2003)
value <- c(10,20,15,NA,5)
mydf<-data.frame(year,value)


mytable <- aggregate(mydf$value, by=list(year), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(mytable) <- c('Year','sum_values')

> mytable
  Year sum_values
1 2001         30
2 2002         15
3 2003          5
```

This [link](http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `rowsum`, which is quite efficient

```
with(mydf, rowsum(value, year, na.rm=TRUE))
#      [,1]
# 2001   30
# 2002   15
# 2003    5
```

Or `tapply`

```
with(mydf, tapply(value, year, sum, na.rm=TRUE))
# 2001 2002 2003 
#   30   15    5
```

Or `as.data.frame(xtabs(...))`

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(mydf[2:1]))
#   year Freq
# 1 2001   30
# 2 2002   15
# 3 2003    5
```

Answer (score 1):

LyzandeR has provided a working answer in base R.  If you want to use `dplyr` which is a great data management tool you could do:

```
year <- c(2001,2001,2002,2002,2003)
value <- c(10,20,15,NA,5)
mydf<-data.frame(year,value)

mydf %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(sum_values = sum(value,na.rm=T))
```

The advantage of `dplyr` in this case is for larger datasets it will be much, *much* faster than base R.  I also believe it's much more readable.